# How to get logged in user's id in main.js in a laravel-vue app?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, laravel-vue

I am currently working in a laravel vue app. I want to get logged in user's is in my main js file.How can I do this?

This method is not working:

This is my main HTML or blade files head tag code

```
<meta name="user_id" content="{{Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->id:'0'}}">
```

Tried to get this in my main.js file like this:

```
let userId=document.head.querySelector('meta[name="user_id"').content;
```

Comment: Did you get answer to this? Need something similar

Comment: No I changed my program some other way